# PHP Code not working in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, version, imagick

Just downloaded this plugin (WordPress PDF Light Viewer) but it wouldn’t activate. I found I had to update my php version but after I did that it would only give the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getVersion() on a non-object in .../wp-content/plugins/pdf-light-viewer/controllers/Plugin.php on line 260
```

After some digging around I’m finding its a problem with this line of code:

```
$Imagick = static::getXMagick();
```

Which is followed by:

```
$ImagickVersion = $Imagick->getVersion();
```

Apparently the preceding line returns null and I can’t find any information on what this code actually does as the only place it shows up in searches is on this plugin.

So, I think I need to find a way to pull $Imagick as an object so the getVersion() can properly run on it. If I'm guessing right, that's the question I need answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF Light viewer requires either [Imagemagik or GMagik.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pdf-light-viewer/) In addition, it needs the Imagick or Gmagick PECL library.

My guess is that your Wordpress server needs these installed. The static `getXMagick()` function must be instantiating a PECL Imagick object (which wraps Imagemagik) but not finding it as part of your PHP installation.

To install Imagemagick on Ubuntu (for PHP 5):
`apt-get install imagemagick php5-imagick`

Comment: This would be on the server itself, correct? The plugin does have Imagick as part of it.

Comment: Correct. Do you have access or the ability to add plugins to the PHP installation on your server? But if it came with it, then I would expect the plugin to be able to find it.

Comment: I just reviewed the documentation that comes with the plugin. It says that Imagemagick is a requirement, but it doesn't look like it is supplied (I would be surprised if it was).

Comment: My host does say that Imagick is turned on on all their servers (http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/software/using-imagemagick) though it states "However, it can only be accessed through the command line, a cron job or PHP code on a web page. The path for the command line options would look like this:

/usr/bin/convert
/usr/bin/mogrify"     So, I'm guessing I need to rework the plugin code to access it this way?

Comment: Well, the plugin is using an `Imagick` object, whereas Inmotionhosting's suggestion is to use Imagemagick through the command line. Their PHP example even uses the command line. They make reference to the 'Imagick' object (http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) but they don't use it in their example. I would call their support and make sure that the Imagick PECL extension is installed on your shared host.

Comment: Contacted my host and they won't install Imagick on shared hosting. So, that's the issue.